# How to Visualize a compressible surface in 3-manifold $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology, minimal-surfaces

I am now reading 'A Course in Minimal Surfaces' written by Tobias Colding & William Minicozzi with helping the [following lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdfJxt87xTg&t=1840s). The lecturer explains an *essential sphere* during the lecture but I do not know what is an essential sphere. Thus I want to delve into compressible surface (or incompressible surface) because google shows the keyword *compressible surface* instead of *essential sphere* to me. And I think that an essential sphere/surface is same as a compressible sphere/surface.

Anyway, my problem is here : I cannot imagine '[compressing surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_surface)' from the Wikipedia (and I cannot find any reference about the concept of compressing surface) To begin with, the definition of compressing disk $D$ is like this,

> **Definition**. Let $S$ be compact surface properly embedded in a smooth $3$-manifold $M$. Then a **compressing disk** $D$ is a disk
> embedded in $M$ such that $D\cap S= \partial D$

I can describe the compressing disk like the below figure. (But because $S$  is $3$-manifold, i.e  locally looks like Euclidean 3-dimensional space, the below image is a projection image onto the plane) As following definition, the only overlapping region between compact surface $S$ and disk $D$ is only the boundary of $D$

[image]

But, the next definition 'a non-trivial disk inside of $S$' is not easy to understand for me.

> **Definition**. If the curve $\partial D $ does not bound a disk inside of $S$, the $D$ is called **a non-trivial compressing disk**. If $S$ has a non-trivial compressing disk, then we call $S$ a **compressible surface** in $M$

**Here is my attempting to understand the definition of non-trivial disk** :

If the above figure  exactly describes the compressing disk , **the** curve $\partial D $ is clearly the lime circle and I pick **a** disk inside of $S$ like this. For convenience, I denote new disk inside $S$ by $D'$

[image]

And what is that the curve $\partial D $ does not bound a disk inside of $S$ ?To begin with, the disk $D'$ in $S$ would never intersect to the disk $D$ except the region of $\partial D $. Because of this, I cannot understand the verb 'bound'. So, the only visualization that I can imagine is that the center of radius of disk $D'$ moves into center of radius $D$.(making concentric circles)

[image]

Then since $D'$, the disk inside of $S$, is not bounded by the curve $\partial D$, $D$ is a non-trivial compressing disk. That means, I can construct a disk inside of $S$ whose radius is bigger than those of disk $D$.   (and since $S$ has one compressing disk, $S$ is compressible surface in $M$). //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try to understand some examples of compressible surfaces instead of trying to visualize the most general ones. Consider the solid torus $M=S^1\times D^2$; its boundary is the torus $T^2=S^1\times S^1$. This boundary surface is compressible in $M$ because of existence of the disk $\{z\}\times D^2$: Its boundary loop $\{z\}\times S^1$ does not bound a disk in $T^2$ but does bound a disk in $M$. As a next example, consider the same solid torus but embedded in $R^3$. Then its boundary $T^2$ is a compressible surface in $R^3$. As a next task, find a compressible surface of genus $g\ge 2$ in $R^3$.